# how to set button below while creating textview programatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have one button to create textview and edittext programmatically,everything works fine but the issue is when textview and edittext generated button is appear above the textview and edittext,i want to set button below of them,following is my code can any one tell what is the issue?

```
addnewdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MainActivity.this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
                    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                            .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                            totalFields++;
                                            lnr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addnewlinear);
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                            lp.setMargins(25, 0, 0, 0);
                                            valueTV = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                            // valueTV.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                            valueTV.setText(userInput.getText());
                                            valueTV.setLayoutParams(lp);
                                            valueTV.setTextSize(18);
                                            valueTV.setTag("tv_" + totalFields);
                                            valueTV.setId(totalFields);
                                            valueTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2d6cae"));
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                            lp1.setMargins(25, 0, 25, 0);
                                            lp1.height = 50;

                                            EditText edtvalues = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

                                            edtvalues.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rect_edt);
                                            edtvalues.setLayoutParams(lp1);
                                            edtvalues.setTag("ed_" + totalFields);
                                            lnr.addView(valueTV);
                                            lnr.addView(edtvalues);
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
            });
```

[image]

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"


    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="IT ADD$"
            android:id="@+id/itaddestxt"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="UP"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itaddestxt"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/addnewlinear"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ADD NEW EVENT"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/txtaddnewevent"
                android:textColor="#73b5fa"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtaddnewevent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/bluelines"
                />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name of Event:*"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bluelines"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#2d6cae"
                android:id="@+id/txtnameofevent"
                />


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/edtnameofevent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtnameofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date of Event:*"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtnameofevent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#2d6cae"
                android:id="@+id/txtdateofevent"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtdateofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/reledtdate"
                >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/edtdateofevent"
                />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edtdateofevent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/calndrdat"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time of Event:*"
                android:layout_below="@+id/reledtdate"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#2d6cae"
                android:id="@+id/txttimeofevent"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txttimeofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/reledttime"
                >
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/edttimeofevent"

                />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edttimeofevent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/timepickrs"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Duration of Event:*"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edttimeofevent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#2d6cae"
                android:id="@+id/txtdurationofevent"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/edtdurationofevent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtdurationofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtdurationofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/addnewdata"
                android:text="Add"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/btnsubmit"
                />

            </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout xml.

Comment: did you set the orientation of your linear layout programmatically?

YOUR_LINEAR_LAYOUT.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

Comment: @SarthakMittal no idint

Comment: you noticed addnewlinear is a LinearLayout in vertical orientation always add below of its siblings.

Comment: but i need my button below of textview and edittext

Comment: Instead of directly adding your edit text into lnr layout means addnewlinear layout make one linearlayout above submit button which has no component within it and visibility gone or invisible and add those component into that layout after make that linearlayout visible.

Comment: @JayShah can you paste answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new layout (linear or relative) above the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"


>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="IT ADD$"
        android:id="@+id/itaddestxt"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="UP"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itaddestxt"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ADD NEW EVENT"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtaddnewevent"
            android:textColor="#73b5fa"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtaddnewevent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/bluelines"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name of Event:*"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bluelines"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#2d6cae"
            android:id="@+id/txtnameofevent"
            />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/edtnameofevent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtnameofevent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date of Event:*"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edtnameofevent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#2d6cae"
            android:id="@+id/txtdateofevent"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtdateofevent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/reledtdate"
            >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/edtdateofevent"
            />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edtdateofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/calndrdat"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time of Event:*"
            android:layout_below="@+id/reledtdate"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#2d6cae"
            android:id="@+id/txttimeofevent"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txttimeofevent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/reledttime"
            >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/edttimeofevent"

            />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edttimeofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/timepickrs"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Duration of Event:*"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edttimeofevent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#2d6cae"
            android:id="@+id/txtdurationofevent"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/edtdurationofevent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtdurationofevent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            />
       <!--Empty layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/addnewlinear"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edtdurationofevent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/addnewdata"
            android:text="Add"
            />        

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/btnsubmit"
            />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```